# General Strategy: Data/Array Analysis in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, data-analysis

This is a strategy question.

I just completed a task in VBA and SQL, that I would not know how to execute in Python because I'm just learning, and am interested in what the general approach would look like in Python.

I have three tables/matrices/arrays.

Names and IDs:

```
Name   NID
Amy    1
Becky  2
Cathy  3
Dana   4
```

Objects with associated names and a date:

```
OID   Names       Date
1a    Amy, Cathy  3/1/2012
2x    Dana        3/1/2011
4s    Amy, Becky  3/1/2010
```

Date ranges associated with NIDs:

```
NID   Start     End
3     1/1/2012  1/1/2013
```

The question I want an answer to is: for every NID in the last matrix, what OIDs are relevant (i.e. the Name appears in the object and the date falls within the date range given for that name in the final matrix)?

It's a broad question, but would be ecstatic to execute this kind of task in python if possible.  Please note that as few as 1 and as many as 1,000 distinct names can be assiacted with an OID.

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't you keep this data in a SQL database? SQL would be well suited for handling the kind of operations you want to perform and it seems like you're already familiar with it. Doing so also has the added advantage of portability, so you can switch between VBA and Python without having to port a ton of code over.

For MySQL I would recommend looking into the `MySQLdb` module. You can take a look at the [official documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) here, and I suggest looking at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm) more user-friendly tutorial.

If you want to do some fast prototyping without having to setup a MySQL server you can use SQLite instead. In that case I would take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)  for the `sqlite3` module.

Comment: [MySQLdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) is obsolete (last updated 2013). Use [mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) instead.